# can custom links be used to load pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming

In wordpress when we are customizing a menu, we can add custom links as menu items in it. Can these links be used to access the pages created in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is yes. If I understand the question what you would actually be doing is creating a custom "title". If the page exists in WordPress it should be available via the menu, and the title can be change to whatever you wish. If for some reason your page doesn't show up in the pages list of the custom menu section you can always use the custom links input area to ad whatever link you need.